# MS SQL Server fix consistency errors in TFS 2017 database for index plan_persist_runtime_stats_cidx

Tags: sql-server, indexing, repair

We have an instance of TFS 2017 installed which is reporting some consistency errors in one of our TFS Collection databases and we're having issues trying to repair it.

The first line in our error log reads as follows...

> Msg 2511, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Table error: Object ID 213575799, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594040942592, alloc unit ID 72057594046513152 (type In-row data). Keys out of order on page (1:12799), slots 28 and 29.

Running the following command I found that the table in question is "plan_persists_runtime_stats"

```
select * from sysobjects where id = 213575799
```

While Googling I found a page that suggested this might be a corrupt index, and the post suggested we should run the following to find the name of the index...

```
select name from sysindexes where id=213575799 and indid=1
```

I found that the object ID appears to be an index "plan_persists_runtime_stats_cidx"

To verify that some of the information I'd found using these scripts, I ran the following...

```
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'plan_persist_runtime_stats_cidx'
```

which gave me object id "213575799", matching the object id reported.

Then I ran the following to try to verify the table name...

```
Select * from sys.tables where object_id = '213575799'
```

This returned 0 rows, which I find odd, but accept this might not be as odd as I find it. I'd be more than happy to receive any information on this.

However, I ran the following to check the table anyway...

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE ('sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats');
```

This returned my list of errors. (the first line of which is shown above).

But, when I ran the following, SQL gave the following message?

```
DBCC DBREINDEX ('sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats');
```

> Cannot find a table or object with the name "sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats". Check the system catalog.

Does anyone know how to correctly rebuild the index that's reporting my errors as I seem to have hit a brick wall now? There are 70 errors in total, and they all relate to the same table object 213575799.

Comment: That's an internal table -- it won't show up in `sys.tables` but only in `sys.internal_tables`, and the engine will pretend it does not exist for regular operations unless you connect using the Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC) (although it's not fully consistent about this, as you've noticed). When connected with the DAC (`sqlcmd -A`, `admin:<instance>` in SSMS) `DBCC DBREINDEX` does work.

Comment: Thanks for this Jeroen, that helped us run the DBRebuild command. Unfortunately, after connecting to our SQL Server and running the command in an admin sqlcmd session, we now get a message saying the "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" statement was terminated because a duplicate key was found for the table.

Comment: Note that if you can't get this table consistent again, consider just nuking it -- this table is part of Query Store, and clearing that out will not affect any business data in the database (it might cause performance or monitoring regressions if it's currently used for that, though). `ALTER DATABASE [db] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR` should do; manually truncating the table in the DAC [should also work](https://joshthecoder.com/2018/11/22/manually-clearing-the-query-store.html) but may leave things inconsistent if you don't clear the rest as well. After this a full `DBCC CHECKDB` should be done.

Comment: And although it *should* go without saying, I'll say it anyway: the first approach to fixing an inconsistent database should be restoring from backup (after verifying the hardware), rather than running logic to fix it (which won't always work). If this is the moment you find out no useful backup policy was in place, this is also the moment to correct that. If all else fails, verify that at least the user tables are OK by running `DBCC CHECKTABLE` on those, and then you can use the import/export wizard to copy over that data to a new DB at least.